# How to decode a signed int into its RGB values

Tags: java, android

I have a number representing a color in an Android (from what I understand is called a signed int because Java has no unsigned ints?)

```
-256
```

I believe this corresponds to the color in hex which appears to be a yellow with transparency set to 0%

```
0xffffff00
```

I try to convert `-256` into its RGB values and load the bytes into an array

```
byteArr[0] = (byte) ((color >> 16) & 0xFF); 
byteArr[1] = (byte) ((color >>  8) & 0xFF); 
byteArr[2] = (byte) ((color >>  0) & 0xFF);
```

When I print the string value of the bytes I get

```
String.valueOf(byteArr[0]); // prints -1
String.valueOf(byteArr[1]); // prints -1
String.valueOf(byteArr[2]); // prints  0
```

I was expected the RGB value of yellow

```
String.valueOf(byteArr[0]); // should print 255
String.valueOf(byteArr[1]); // should print 255
String.valueOf(byteArr[2]); // should print 0
```

Can anyone help me convert to the actual RGB values of `-256` and help me wrap my head around what is happening?

Thanks

Comment: bytes are signed too...

Answer (score 0):

You can encode and decode RGB colors like this

```
 // sRGB
 Color opaqueRed = Color.valueOf(0xffff0000); // from a color int
 Color translucentRed = Color.valueOf(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f);
```

for more details see [Color](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html).

Comment: Why does `String.valueOf((byte) Color.blue(-11922228))` print out `-52` where   `String.valueOf((byte) Color.red(-11922228))` prints `74`? Isn't `74` the red component unsigned, and `-52` the signed blue component? How can I get unsigned blue component?